# Missing 1 pin in my Ethernet Port - Can I get 1gbit again?

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, network-adapter, cable

One of the pins inside my Ethernet port on my laptop was bent, so I tried to correct it but it broke off.
It's the leftmost one (it connects to the white/orange cable).
My internet is working but I'm getting a 100mbit connection.
So my question is, can I change/reroute some cables inside the network cable to get it back at 1gbit, or do I need to buy an USB network adapter?

Comment: Is this a desktop or laptop? You can but good PCI network interface cards [NICs] for next to nothing these days, maybe $£€ 10 - 30

Comment: A laptop, but a network adapter is also as low as 20 euros.

Comment: Sure - but it's one more "tinker's donkey" accessory to hang from your lappy. I remember when all these peripherals were internal ;))

Comment: Pragmatic approach: if you only use the Ethernet port for Internet access, and your DSL connection is <= 100 Mbit, an Ethernet port limited to 100 Mbit wouldn't be a problem...

Comment: No my speed is 150, and on work we have an internal 1gbit connection. PCMIA cards you mean Tetsujin, I remember that, way better then external.

Comment: Is this a work computer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gigabit ethernet requires all 8 pins to connect.  See the diagram below:

[image]

You can buy a gigabit to USB adapter.

Alternatively, the ethernet port can probably be replaced in the laptop by someone good at soldering.  Check computer repair shops in your area and ask them if they can remove and replace it.  Not all shops do soldering work.

Comment: Warning to the poster: If the soldering is badly done, motherboard replacement might be required. Also, finding a port of identical dimensions may not be easy. A new USB adapter is a safer solution.

Comment: Thanks I could not find that image, how is 100mbit working with the first missing? Its marked for transmit+ on your image. And Im not bothering to soldering it because gigabit adapters are less expensive with no risks.

Comment: @FamousWolluf It depends if by leftmost you mean looking into the socket, or at the plug, and which way up. https://www.showmecables.com/blog/post/rj45-pinout has some images with the numbering on connectors, but I think the pin you have broken is pin 8, not pin 1.

Comment: @FamousWolluf It could also be that modern switches and network circuits can auto-detect a cross-over cable vs a straight cable. If it detects that pin 1 is not connected, it changes to cross-over mode and see if that works.

Comment: @pipe Even in crossover mode, it would still require all four pins for the 100mbit mode to work.

Comment: @FamousWolluf For historical reasons, 100mbps mode only uses half the pins. this famously means you can rewire a cable so you can get 2 connections over the same cable.

Comment: @user1937198, no was looking inside rhe port and compared ith with a Lan cable, Im also an IT technician so I know much, but did not know which cables where for what. But I also stream on Twitch and I noticed that yesterday I got an unstable connection and it disconnected my stream once a hour, but Discord remaind working, so I get hickups in the connection. So I will defenitly buy an external usb networkadapter